# Specifiy colors for labels in alt.Chart()

Tags: python-3.x, scatter-plot, altair

Let's say I would like to plot `['foo', 'bar', 'test']` with the respective colors `['blue', 'yellow', 'green']`. My suggestion to solve this is as following:

```
alt.Chart(df, height=600, width=1100).mark_circle(size=100).encode(
        x='x',
        y='y',
        color=alt.Color('title:N', legend=None, scale=alt.Scale(range=['blue', 'yellow', 'green'])),
        tooltip=['sample', 'title']
    ).properties(
        selection=click
    ).interactive()
```

But this seems to pick the colors in an arbitrary order, and not in an ascending order as I expected. I would like `foo` to be assigned the `blue` color and `bar` should become `yellow` and so on.

Is it possible to link this (labels and colors) somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some information on this in the docs in the [Customizing Colors](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/customization.html#customizing-colors) section. Briefly, if you would like to control which values are assigned to which colors, you can use the `domain` argument:

```
scale = alt.Scale(domain=['foo', 'bar', 'test'], range=['blue', 'yellow', 'green'])
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This was exactly what I was looking for